# ReactJSL: Enum value map from JSON response

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I'm receiving a `JSON response` which is an array of `INT's`. I'm currently learning ReactJS and coming from a Swift background. Normally in swift I would have an enum and then use the response array to return the associated string for the `INT`. Does ReactJS offer a similar solution? I've tried building an array and then mapping each value to a label but it looks messy and maybe overkill. My `JSON response` is:

```
types: [1,4,3,8,5,8]
```

And I have a const array:

```
const options = ['Good times', 'Bad times' ...]
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
typeOptions = [{label: "Good times", value: 1}, {label: "Bad times", value: 2}...]
```

I would be able then to call the value as `typeOptions.label`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and generate an array of object mapping values in the options array and value at that index in the `types` array.

```js
const types = [1,4,3],
      options = ['Good times', 'Bad times', 'Worse times'],
      result = options.map((label,i) => ({label, value: types[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner!